# Is there a way to parse multi-row json table in Snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake table that contains some json as the only field. In order to parse it, I had to use the following construction:

```
select value:some_field
from table(flatten(select raw_data from json_table)) t;
```

which only works if the `json_table` has just one row, otherwise I receive the `Single-row subquery returns more than one row.`error. Given that there can be multiple jsons inserted into a table at pretty much the same moment, is there a way to make this work for multi-row situations?

Example: data in the source table looks like this:

```
raw_data
[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 0}]
[{a: -1, b: 4}, {a: 17, b: -6}]
```

What I want to be happening is each row gets parsed (which was possible with just one row and `table(flatten(select raw_data from json_table))` so that each object gets a row assigned to it. Having said that, the target view should look like this:

```
a  b
1  2
3  0
-1 4
17 -6
```

Comment: Give us some sample data and desired results please

Comment: Done! I think this should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! It's that sample data just one row? A single json object with an array of objects?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark this as code, these are two different rows actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reproduces the error:

```sql
with json_table as (
    select parse_json('[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 0}]') raw_data 
    union all select parse_json('[{a: -1, b: 4}, {a: 17, b: -6}]')
)

select value:a, value:b
from table(flatten(select raw_data from json_table)) t;

-- Single-row subquery returns more than one row.
```

This fixes it:

```sql
with json_table as (
    select parse_json('[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 0}]') raw_data 
    union all select parse_json('[{a: -1, b: 4}, {a: 17, b: -6}]')
)

select value:a, value:b
from json_table, table(flatten(raw_data)) t;
```

[image]

Instead of doing a sub-select inside the flatten, select from outside, and only unnest inside the flatten.